Why would a parquet file get larger when FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY data type is used for fixed length byte array column?
When trying to store a dataset in a parquet file for uploading it to HuggingFace I've encountered a strange phenomenon: when storing 50-byte array as a column, the file size gets larger when type FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY is used instead of BYTE_ARRAY.
Here is python code demonstrating that observation:
import os
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

tmp_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/tmp/pq") # directory for example files to be stored
n_bytes = 50
n_records = 4096 * 126
np_rng = np.random.default_rng(1)
array = np.frombuffer(
    np_rng.bytes(n_bytes * n_records), dtype=np.dtype((np.bytes_, n_bytes)))
table_byte_array = pa.Table.from_pydict({'byte_data': array})
pq.write_table(table_byte_array, f'{tmp_dir}/byte_array_example.parquet')
table_fixed_len_byte_array = pa.Table.from_pydict(
    {'byte_data': array},
    schema=pa.schema([
        pa.field('byte_data', pa.binary(array.itemsize), nullable=False)]))
pq.write_table(
    table_fixed_len_byte_array,
    f'{tmp_dir}/fixed_len_byte_array_example.parquet')
file_sizes = []
for name in ['byte_array', 'fixed_len_byte_array']:
    filename = f'{tmp_dir}/{name}_example.parquet'
    table = pq.read_table(filename)
    file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    file_sizes.append(file_size)
    print(f'{name}: {table.schema.field("byte_data").type} {file_size}')
print(
    f'size ratio: {file_sizes[1] / file_sizes[0]:.3f}; '
    f'size diff: {file_sizes[1] - file_sizes[0]}')

It prints:
byte_array: binary 25493170
fixed_len_byte_array: fixed_size_binary[50] 25850348
size ratio: 1.014; size diff: 357178

This seems to be very counter-intuitive: not having a per-element length (i.e. storing less data) results in larger file size. Why is that the case?

System info for the above test: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS; Python 3.10.11; pyarrow version 12.0.1 (using parquet-cpp-arrow version 12.0.1). When looking at the output of pqrs schema <name>_example.parquet --detailed, I see the same encoding line for both files: encodings: RLE_DICTIONARY PLAIN RLE PLAIN.

Why file with BYTE_ARRAY column type is smaller?
Because it does not store all input data: line table_byte_array = pa.Table.from_pydict({'byte_data': array}) truncates input entries on first NULL byte. This can be verified by the following example:
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
np_array = np.array([
  b'\x00Very important data. Keep it safe!',
  b'Less important data. Keep it safe??'])
table = pa.Table.from_pydict({'sample': np_array})
print(table['sample'][0].as_py())

One might expect it to print b'\x00Very important data. Keep it safe!' but it prints b'' instead. Also, if some bytes after b'\x00' in an entry in array are modified in the first example, the output .parquet file is identical, confirming that this data is not saved in the output .parquet file. Since this behavior seems to be a bug, I've filed #41388.
So FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY is better, right?
For some applications - maybe, but HuggingFace's datasets library does not support fixed size binary arrays by default:  attempting to load such file without custom loader results in ValueError("Arrow type FixedSizeBinaryType(fixed_size_binary[50]) does not have a datasets dtype equivalent.") from datasets/features/features.py as of datasets version 2.19.0.
How can we store an np.ndarray as BYTE_ARRAY then?
There is a workaround: in the question's code replace the table_byte_array = pa.Table.from_pydict({'byte_data': array}) line with
table_byte_array = pa.Table.from_pydict({
        'byte_data': pa.array(
                array, type=pa.binary(array.itemsize)
            ).cast(target_type=pa.binary())
    })

